# How to loop a "Multiple String" from a ProductBO object in an ISML-Template?

Tags: intershop, isml

How can I loop a Multiple String from a ProductBO object? What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the name of the attribute you may use the following method on `ProductBO` from within an ISML:

`public AttributeValue getAttributeValue(String aName);`

The storefront app comes with a convenient albeit not extremely flexible module that is able to display AV-s. It works for multiple attributes too. The name of the module is `ISCustomAttribute`.

Sample usage:

```
<isCustomAttribute 
    attributelabel="#AttributeDescriptor:DisplayName#" 
    attributevalue="#ProductBO:AttributeValue(AttributeDescriptor:ID)#" 
    attributeseparator=",&nbsp;">
```

The best would be if you use this module. You may see it in action. Custom `ProductBO` attributes are printed on the product details page in the storefront as the next image shows (@see `DetailsTab.isml`):

[image]

If this does not fit, you will have to retrieve the attribs as something iterable. The way I think fits best is to use the BO extension `BusinessObjectAttributes`. You will be able retrieve a `BusinessObjectAttribute` by name from it and loop through its value.

```
<isloop iterator="BusinessObjectAttribute:Value" alias="AValue" counter="counter">
    <!--- Do something gorgeous here --->
</isloop>
```